# Can £ sign be recognised in price span in Microformats?

Tags: microformats

The code inside a hProduct

```
<span class="price">£10.00</span>
```

generates an error in the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) of:

```
Error: Price field includes invalid characters.
```

Changing the code to

```
<span class="price">$10.00</span>
```

Gives no errors.  If I want to keep the £ inside the  is there anyway to change the class etc so it will format properly?

Comment: I assume you are using [hProduct](http://microformats.org/wiki/hproduct)?

Comment: yes sorry, too involved to see the info missing.  Ill update.  Thanks